# make clean in several subdirectories

Tags: make, find, xargs

I want to clean several (>20) subdirectories with `make clean`. I thought about someting like this:

```
find ./ -type d -maxdepth 1 | xargs "make clean"
```

but it doesn't work. Could you please help me?

Comment: How about `find . -maxdepth 2 -name Makefile -execdir make clean \;`, under the assumption that each of these directories will have a `Makefile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to only want to descend into the immediate subdirectories, you can avoid `find` altogether and just run each `make clean` in a subshell e.g.

```
for d in */; do (cd "$d" && make clean); done
```

You can add a test for the existence of a Makefile if you wish, but `make` will fail gracefully if it doesn't find one (or if there is no `clean` target).